# How to re-create the Github post-receive for a private server?

Tags: github, git-post-receive, sprint.ly

I'm using the excellent [Sprint.ly](http://sprint.ly) to manage my project. I'm using git for source control and Sprint.ly has an excellent integration with github by taking its post-receive message and scanning for changes (see [their documentation](http://support.sprint.ly/kb/integration/setting-up-scmvcs-integration)).

I'm **not** using github to host this repo, instead I'm using my own private server. How can I recreate the github post-receive message and post it to sprint.ly? I'm not very good at writing scripts like this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following repository:
https://github.com/mbmccormick/gitosis-webhook

I was able to integrate with sprint.ly using this post-receive script, modifying the URL variable appropriately.

Hope this helps,
Aaron

Comment: Hi Aaron, that works well. I also got another answer pointing to https://github.com/metajack/notify-webhook which is similar but provides more information about the repository. However, I've got an old debian server that i'm running this on and my version of Python doesn't work with this script. Can I send you a pull later today to make some changes so that it better works with sprint.ly i.e. URLs back to the repo?

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I'll take a look at your link as well.  Unfortunately you can't send me a pull on that repo as I'm not affiliated with it, however I'm sure the author in question would appreciate the pull request from you.